# What is this robot/computer music album, with titles involving terms such as "memory" and "fragmentation"?

Tags: robots, computers, music-identification

It must have been 2020 or earlier when, on a (now deleted) tumblr blog, I found a link to some sort of music page (bandcamp perhaps?) with I believe a blue-ish colour scheme that had several tracks that could be listened to gratis. Unfortunately, data loss happened to the only device with which I'd navigated to that page.

It was likely about a dozen tracks all in all. The tracks had titles involving computering terms such as "memory", "loss" or "lost", and "fragmentation" or "fragmented" or "fragments". Unlike those of the musician(s) known as ["MASTER BOOT RECORD"](https://masterbootrecord.bandcamp.com/) however, the terms were more generic and conceptual, not specific file or command names as a lot of MBR's are.

I believe there probably weren't any lyrics, or perhaps there were a few tracks with lyrics but most without. I'd think the kind of it was like experimental, techno / electro, and video game soundtrack-ish. The description or album title or something similar called it something like "music for robots". It wasn't ["Music For Robots" by "Squarepusher x Z-MACHINES"](https://squarepusher.bandcamp.com/album/music-for-robots) though.

Comment: Were the lyrics about something science fiction-based? What sort of music was it? EDM? Nerdcore? Country music? Disco?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: I believe there probably weren't any lyrics, or perhaps there were a few tracks with lyrics but most without. I'd think the kind of it was like experimental, techno / electro, and video game soundtrack ish.

Comment: Was there a sci-fi theme to it? Otherwise, it's not really on-topic here.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Yes, it was. The description or album title or something similar called it something like "music for robots". It wasn't [this "Music For Robots" by "Squarepusher x Z-MACHINES"](https://squarepusher.bandcamp.com/album/music-for-robots) though.

Comment: ^_^ And not https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj8XaD5_pQE or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7Dh-t8XEgU?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: First one no. The second one you linked does sound similar to it but I'm sure the one I'm looking for was at least half a dozen tracks, probably closer to a dozen. That one seems to be just one track. And it wasn't on YouTube that I listened to it, though of course that isn't mutually exclusive.

Comment: [DAN DEAGH WEALCAN – Fragmented Consciousness](https://www.discogs.com/release/9349993-Dan-Deagh-Wealcan-Fragmented-Consciousness) ?

Comment: @Yaroslav Kornachevskyi: Don't think it is this one, thank you!

Comment: I doubt that it ever appeared on Bandcamp, but your description of tracks sounds very much like the OST for Ghost in the Shell:ARISE.

Comment: In particular, the lyrics of the opening segment of the track "jibun ga inai" from GiTS:ARISE are constructed from fragments of a Japanese word for "memory" - ki + o + ku that gradually coalesce and join with fragments of "self" to form a [partial] sentence.

Comment: @Ethan: Thanks for the suggestion, I listened to that track a few times. It isn't a match however.